# .htaccess RewriteRule redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i need help redirecting this two links to one link:

```
Link #1: http://www.domain.com/index.php?til=d_news&id_new=1
Link #2: http://www.domain.com/new_folder/?til=d_news&id_new=1
```

need to redirect to:

```
http://www.domain.com/news/news.html
```

i tried using this code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^til=d_news
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/news/news.html? [R=301,L]
```

but it only redirects the first link and not the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^til=d_news&id_new=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /news/news.html? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the htaccess file in your document root, add:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^til=d_news&id_new=1 
 RewriteRule ^index.php$ /news/news.html? [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^til=d_news&id_new=1
 RewriteRule ^new_folder/?$ /news/news.html? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second link there is no destination page:

```
http://www.domain.com/new_folder/?til=d_news&id_new=1
```

should be something like:

```
http://www.domain.com/new_folder/page.php?til=d_news&id_new=1
```

Comment: yeah i know some old links display like that, thats why i want to redirect